# how to redirect make errors to file

Tags: makefile

I have a hierarchy of build folder contains three modules (say M1, M2 and M3) for that I written a makefile for each module. And also I written a makefile such that it build all three modules with single makefile.

suppose while building three modules if any module encounter an error that errors are redirect one file so that easily find which module errors and if possible mail that file to some one. Please suggest me how to do this scenario and thanks in advance.

SUBDIRS = $(BUILD_DIR)

all: subdirs

subdirs:
    for n in $(SUBDIRS); do $(MAKE) -C $$n || exit 1; done

clean:
    for n in $(SUBDIRS); do $(MAKE) -C $$n clean; done

Note:exporting my modules into SUBDIRS variable

Comment: What does your toplevel makefile look like currently?

Comment: SUBDIRS = $(BUILD_DIR)         

all: subdirs

subdirs:
 for n in $(SUBDIRS); do $(MAKE) -C $$n || exit 1; done
 
 
clean:
 for n in $(SUBDIRS); do $(MAKE) -C $$n clean; done                                                                #note:Exporting my modules into BUILD_DIR variable.

Comment: Put that in your question so you can format it sanely.